# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported (Spring MVC)

Tags: java, javascript, spring, hibernate, methods

Im getting this error: `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported`

What I am trying to do is make a form with a drop down box that get populated based on the other value selected in another drop down box. For example when I select a name in the `customerName` box the `onChange` function in the .jsp page should be run and the page submitted then loaded again with the corresponding values in the `customerCountry` box.

however I'm getting this HTTP Status 405 error. I have searched the internet for a solution but haven't been able to find anything that helped. Here is the relevant parts of my code:

*part of jsp page*

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
            <style>
            .error { color: red; }
            </style>

        <script>
            function repopulate(){  
                document.deliveryForm.submit();
            }

            function setFalse(){
                document.getElementById("hasId").value ="false";
                document.deliveryForm.submit();
                // document.submitForm.submit(); (This was causing the error)

            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>Create New Delivery</h1>

        <c:url var="saveUrl" value="/test/delivery/add" />
        <form:form modelAttribute="deliveryDtoAttribute" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}" name="deliveryForm">
            <table>


                <tr>
                    <td><form:hidden id="hasId" path="hasCustomerName" value="true"/></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Customer Name</td>
                    <td><form:select path="customerName" onChange="repopulate()">
                        <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                        <form:options items="${customerNameList}" />
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="customerName" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Customer Country</td>
                    <td><form:select path="customerCountry">
                        <form:option value="" label="--- Select ---" />
                        <form:options items="${customerCountryList}" />
                        </form:select>
                    </td>
                    <td><form:errors path="customerCountry" cssClass="error" /></td>
                </tr>

        </form:form>

        <form:form name="submitForm">
        <input type="button" value="Save" onClick="setFalse()"/>
        </form:form>

    </body>
</html>
```

*part of controller:*

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getDelivery(ModelMap model) {
        DeliveryDto deliveryDto = new DeliveryDto();

        model.addAttribute("deliveryDtoAttribute", deliveryDto);
        model.addAttribute("customerNameList",
                customerService.listAllCustomerNames());
        model.addAttribute("customerCountryList", customerService
                    .listAllCustomerCountries(deliveryDto.getCustomerName()));
        return "new-delivery";
    }

    // I want to enter this method if hasId=true which means that a value in the CustomerName 
    // drop down list was selected. This should set the CountryList to the corresponding values 
    // from the database. I want this post method to be triggered by the onChange in the jsp page

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="hasCustomerName=true")
    public String postDelivery(
            @ModelAttribute("deliveryDtoAttribute") DeliveryDto deliveryDto,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {


            model.addAttribute("deliveryDtoAttribute", deliveryDto);

            model.addAttribute("customerNameList",
                    customerService.listAllCustomerNames());
            model.addAttribute("customerCountryList", customerService
                    .listAllCustomerCountries(deliveryDto.getCustomerName()));

            return "new-delivery";
    }

    // This next post method should only be entered if the save button is hit in the jsp page

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST, params="hasCustomerName=false")
    public String postDelivery2(
            @ModelAttribute("deliveryDtoAttribute") @Valid DeliveryDto deliveryDto,
            BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {

            model.addAttribute("deliveryDtoAttribute", deliveryDto);

            model.addAttribute("customerNameList",
                    customerService.listAllCustomerNames());
            model.addAttribute("customerCountryList", customerService
                    .listAllCustomerCountries(deliveryDto.getCustomerName()));

            return "new-delivery";
        } else {

            Delivery delivery = new Delivery();

            //Setters to set delivery values

            return "redirect:/mis/home";
        }

    }
```

How come I get this error? Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

**EDIT:** Changed `hasId` to `hasCustomerName`. I still get the `HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported` error though.

**EDIT2:** Commented out the line in the `setFalse` function that was causing the error

// D

Comment: Why the vote down? Please provide me with an explanation so that I can post better questions in the future. Thanks

Comment: for people hitting this issue and coming on this page, also check that the defined action hits an existing endpoint, that was my problem :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem that was causing the HTTP error.

In the `setFalse()` function that is triggered by the Save button my code was trying to submit the form that contained the button.

```
        function setFalse(){
            document.getElementById("hasId").value ="false";
            document.deliveryForm.submit();
            document.submitForm.submit();
```

when I remove the `document.submitForm.submit();` it works:

```
        function setFalse(){
            document.getElementById("hasId").value ="false";
            document.deliveryForm.submit()
```

@Roger Lindsjö Thank you for spotting my error where I wasn't passing on the right parameter!

Answer (score 23):

I am not sure if this helps but I had the same problem.

You are using springSecurityFilterChain with CSRF protection. That means you have to send a token when you send a form via POST request. Try to add the next input to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: How to disable this filter chain temperately?  because have so many methods to change, I want it first works, then upgrade gradually

Comment: @YuJiaao - you can find it in the Spring Security reference, chapter 18.4.2 https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-configure

Answer (score 19):

**Check if you are returning a @ResponseBody or a @ResponseStatus**

I had a similar problem. My Controller looked like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user).getId();
}
```

When calling with a POST request I always got the following error:

**HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported**

After a while I figured out that the method was actually called, but because there is no @ResponseBody and no @ResponseStatus Spring MVC raises the error.

To fix this simply add a @ResponseBody

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user).getId();
}
```

or a @ResponseStatus to your method.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
public String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    return userService.updateUser(user).getId();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You might need to change the line

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
```

Comment: No, there are two methods, one for each RequestMethod.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your controller expect a parameter *hasId=false* or *hasId=true*, but you are not passing that. Your hidden field has the id *hasId* but is passed as *hasCustomerName*, so no mapping matches.

Either change the path of the hidden field to *hasId* or the mapping parameter to expect *hasCustomerName=true* or *hasCustomerName=false*.

Comment: I see I was a little tired when I wrote this. Good eye! I am still getting the exact same error though. Any Ideas what it could be?

Comment: How come the error message is so misleading ? It leads us to think it is an HTTP verb issue when in fact it is a parameter one.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the url was ending with /

paymentUrl(old)= /get-details/

i just removed the trailing /

paymentUrl(new)= /get-details

and it worked

Comment: Removed the trailing slash in @RequestMapping(value="/user" and it worked for me! I guess it should match with the caller too.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar problem for other reason (url pattern `test-response`  not added in csrf token)
I resolved it by allowing my URL pattern in following property in `config/local.properties`:

`csrf.allowed.url.patterns = /[^/]+(/[^?])+(sop-response)$,/[^/]+(/[^?])+(merchant_callback)$,/[^/]+(/[^?])+(hop-response)$`

modified to

`csrf.allowed.url.patterns = /[^/]+(/[^?])+(sop-response)$,/[^/]+(/[^?])+(merchant_callback)$,/[^/]+(/[^?])+(hop-response)$,/[^/]+(/[^?])+(test-response)$`