# Request method 'POST' not supported - SPRING

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

login.jsp

```
<div id="login" class="animate form">
                    <form action="${loginUrl}" method="POST">
                        <h1>Log in</h1>

                        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
                        <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
                            <input type="text" class="alert-danger" id="danger" name="danger"
                                placeholder="Invalid username and password." disabled />
                            <br />
                        </c:if>
                        <c:if test="${param.logout != null}">
                            <input type="text" class="alert-success" id="success"
                                name="success"
                                placeholder="You have been logged out successfully." disabled />
                            <br />
                        </c:if>


                        <p>
                            <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u"> Your
                                email </label> <input id="username" name="login" required="required"
                                type="text" placeholder="mymail@atos.net" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">
                                Your password </label> <input id="password" name="password"
                                required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="keeplogin">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" id="rememberme"
                                value="rememberme" /> <label for="rememberme">Remember
                                Me</label>
                        </p>
                        <p class="login button">
                            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
                        </p>
                        <p class="change_link"></p>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

userlist.jsp

```
<div class="generic-container">
        <%@include file="authheader.jsp" %>   
        <div class="panel panel-default">
              <!-- Default panel contents -->
            <div class="panel-heading"><span class="lead">List of Users </span></div>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Prenom</th>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th>Matricule</th>
                        <th>Login</th>
                        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('READ')">
                            <th width="100"></th>
                        </sec:authorize>
                        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                            <th width="100"></th>
                        </sec:authorize>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                    <tr>
                        <td>${user.prenom}</td>
                        <td>${user.nom}</td>
                        <td>${user.matricule}</td>
                        <td>${user.login}</td>
                        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN') or hasRole('READ')">
                            <td><a href="<c:url value='/edit-user-${user.login}' />" class="btn btn-success custom-width">edit</a></td>
                        </sec:authorize>
                        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
                            <td><a href="<c:url value='/delete-user-${user.login}' />" class="btn btn-danger custom-width">delete</a></td>
                        </sec:authorize>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
            <div class="well">
                <a href="<c:url value='/newuser' />">Add New User</a>
            </div>
        </sec:authorize>
    </div>
```

AppController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@SessionAttributes("roles")
public class AppController {

    @Autowired
    IService_User<USER> userService;

    @Autowired
    IService<COMPTE> compteService;

    @Autowired
    MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices persistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices;

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver;

@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {

        List<USER> users = userService.findAllOBJECTS();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        model.addAttribute("loggedinuser", getPrincipal());
        return "userslist";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }
}
```

There are 2 pages: login.jsp - start page which includes form to be populated with login and password - userlist.jsp list of results "display all users persisted in DB"..
First the login page is shown, when i click on submit button i got this error:
**org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported**

Answer (score 1):

In your login.jsp you are using http method POST

```
<form action="${loginUrl}" method="POST">
```

and in controller, you are using http method GET

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }
```

Problem will be solved after changing method = RequestMethod.POST in your controller like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your login form you are explicitly making an POST request...  and in your controller the the url is mapped to GET request.. this is the issue... Please make the controller as POST... like

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginPage() {
        if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
            return "login";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/list";
        }
    }
```

Comment: In your login.jsp page ... Your variable "loginUrl" is empty/null ...  Please move the line  " <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />"   line above the div tag/out of the div tag    " <div id="login" class="animate form"> "

Comment: @FuSsA  Please try tis,.. In your login.jsp page ... Your variable "loginUrl" is empty/null ... Please move the line " <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />"  above the div tag/out of the div tag " <div id="login" class="animate form"> "

Comment: @FuSsA  Plese map value of your loginUrl to "//login"   something like "   <c:url var="loginUrl" value="//login" />  "   ... because at the top of the controller you have give "/" as RequestMapping..

Answer (score 0):

Add `post` method in `@RequestMapping` annotation, like following;)

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/login"}, method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String loginPage() {
    if (isCurrentAuthenticationAnonymous()) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "redirect:/list";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try to clean your project and rebuild it, and then publish it to your web container? I want to confirm if it's build problem.

Comment: It's weird, please check this [HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported (Spring MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145884/http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported-spring-mvc), maybe the top voteup answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring security 4.x.x. , CSRF is enabled by default. therefore you have to provide the csrf filed in your form.

Adding the csrf token as hidden fields does the trick:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```