# Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

I have a spring-Boot application, and 
I am trying to send an object using post method to the below controller:

```
@PostMapping("/suggestevent")
    public String receiveSuggestedEvent(@ModelAttribute SuggestedEvent event) {

        return "redirect:/suggestEvent";
    }
```

but it complains with:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'POST' not supported
```

So, what is wrong?

Update:
I have tried this and it also did not work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/suggestevent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

The form contains some simple inputes, and a select, which works based on Thyemeleaf. Here is my form:

```
<form th:action="@{/suggestevent}" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Event title"
                        th:value="${event.title}"
                        name="title" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mainFouce">Main Focus</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="Focus" placeholder="Focus"
                        th:value="${event.mainFouce}"
                        name="Focus" required="required"/>
                </div>

                Event Type
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="type" th:value="${event.type}">
                        <option value="volvo">Party</option>
                        <option value="saab">Workshop</option>
                        <option value="fiat">Friendship</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">Area</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="area"
                        th:value="${event.area}"
                        placeholder="Berlin, Estonia ,or even Asia" name="area"
                        required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control"
                        th:value="${event.description}"
                        required="required" form="usrform"
                        placeholder="What makes it an special event?"></textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

The sent object is:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class SuggestedEvent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    String title;
    String mainFouce;
    EventType type;
    String area;
    String description;

}
```

**The postman can successfully reach the controller, but the thyemeleaf complains!!!**

Comment: Could have numerous reasons. Did you check [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Request+method+%27POST%27+not+supported)? There seem to be many people having the same problem.

Comment: Add the input field if you are using CSRF protection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145884/http-status-405-request-method-post-not-supported-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you try to add an empty `SuggestedEvent` object inside the form and try to populate that object like so:

```
<form th:action="@{/suggestevent}" th:object="${event}"  method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Event title"
                        th:value="*{title}"
                        name="title" required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mainFouce">Main Focus</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="Focus" placeholder="Focus"
                        th:value="*{mainFouce}"
                        name="Focus" required="required"/>
                </div>

                Event Type
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" name="type" th:value="*{type}">
                        <option value="volvo">Party</option>
                        <option value="saab">Workshop</option>
                        <option value="fiat">Friendship</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">Area</label>
                     <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" id="area"
                        th:value="*{area}"
                        placeholder="Berlin, Estonia ,or even Asia" name="area"
                        required="required"/>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <textarea name="description" class="form-control"
                        th:value="*{description}"
                        required="required" form="usrform"
                        placeholder="What makes it an special event?"></textarea>
                </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in the `@GetMapping("/suggestEvent")`:

```
  @GetMapping("/suggestEvent")
  public String getSuggestEventPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("event", new SuggestEvent());

    return "suggestEventPage";
  }
```

Check out the official Thymeleaf doc otherwise. This shouldn't really be a problem, since I am doing the exact same thing in [my project](https://github.com/yoshuaNahar/InfoSupport-Minor/blob/master/case1/src/main/java/nl/infosupport/javaminor/case1/resources/StudentController.java#L43).

> http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standarddialect5minutes.html
>   http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html
>   http://www.thymeleaf.org/documentation.html